# Write a dataframe with different number of decimal places per column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, decimal

I need to generate a dataframe or data.table which has different number of decimal places per column.

For example:

```
Scale       Status
1.874521    1
```

Needs to be print in a CSV as:

```
Scale,      Status
1.874521,   1.000
```

This has to be as a numeric value as I have tried `format(DF$status, digits=3)` and `as.numeric(format(DF$status, digits=3))` however this converts it to characters which when exported to CSV has double quotes ".

My actual dataframe has lots of columns with different amounts of decimal places required as well as characters which do need to be double quoted so I can't apply a system wide change.

Comment: `write.csv` has a `quote` option that you can set to `FALSE`.

Comment: you can use `quote = FALSE` in `write.csv`??

Comment: `quote=FALSE` would definitely do what he's asking. I just wonder if in the `data.frame` he has there are also character columns that need to be printed _with_ the double quote.

Comment: @Michele is right that I can't set `quote=FALSE` due to some character columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better option than doing `quote=FALSE`, is to actually specify which columns you want quoted, as the `quote` param can be a vector of column indices which you want to be quoted. E.g.

```
d = data.table(a = c("a", "b"), b = c(1.234, 1.345), c = c(1, 2.1))
d[, b := format(b, digits = 2)]
d[, c := format(c, nsmall = 3)]
d
#   a   b     c
#1: a 1.2 1.000
#2: b 1.3 2.100

write.csv(d, 'file.csv', quote = c(1,2), row.names = F)
#file.csv:
#"a","b","c"
#"a","1.2",1.000
#"b","1.3",2.100
```

Comment: Thanks for this much appreciated. I have a working solution now using `as.data.table(DF[,STATUS:= format(STATUS, nsmall=3)])` and adding the vector to the quote parameter. Very simple and elegant solution. thanks.