# How to apply a function to each element/cell of a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, sapply

I want to round to two decimal digits values which are small and to integer values which are large. I want to get `desired.df` from `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0.123, 123.456), b = c(321.321, 0.321))
desired.df <- data.frame(a = c(0.12, 123), b = c(321, 0.32))

df
#         a       b
# 1   0.123 321.321
# 2 123.456   0.321

desired.df
#        a      b
# 1   0.12    321
# 2    123   0.32
```

How to do this? I have tried `apply` and some of its variants, obviously in not the proper way, as well as nesting *apply functions (like `*apply(df, function(x) *apply(y, function(y) ...))`), but without luck...

For example, the following does not work

```
round.my.way <- function(cell) {
if(cell < 2) return(round(cell, 2)) 
else return(round(cell, 0))
}

apply(df, 1:2, round.my.way)
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I am really sorry I did not emphasize that the posted `desired.df` has more to do probably about formatting each "cell" independently in a data frame, but I had not realized that.

```
my.data.frame <- structure(list(mean = c(1.09586889552429, -0.488970742717109,                        
717.369670482251, 1430.22132153487), sd = c(14.6805055234266,                        
0.847924955832248, 3148.43113658712, 6224.1150344482), skew = c(15.4288196192469,    
-0.848099854154573, 15.6753519251057, 13.8872189273213), kurt = c(760.003399845995,  
3.42534233994167, 403.114382084221, 296.372235189872), min = c(0.0211657925274003, 
-6.63384131834086, 1.14376333333333, 1.51974013933333), X5.. = c(0.163422411626505, 
-1.94866860909688, 5.55001008333333, 8.48210945666667), X25.. = c(0.419624647887877, 
-0.940344070376478, 24.2286483333333, 40.2822858746667), median = c(0.712376790798036, 
-0.397878278400871, 79.5970091666667, 147.535862094), X75.. = c(1.11275078144806, 
0.0525922423468574, 300.39765875, 594.258755956833), X95.. = c(2.12897531610479, 
0.694437497721256, 2918.320405, 5614.78688014776), max = c(932.099715965617, 
3.36571976522158, 77776.31031, 151194.931773039), n = c(4046.23166666667, 
4046.23166666667, 4046.23166666667, 4046.23166666667)), .Names = c("mean", 
"sd", "skew", "kurt", "min", "X5..", "X25..", "median", "X75..", 
"X95..", "max", "n"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

With one of my experiments, I almost get what I want:

```
apply(my.data.frame, c(1, 2), function(x) if(x < 2) round(x, 2) else round(x, 0))
```

produces:

```
     mean      sd  skew kurt   min  X5.. X25.. median  X75..   X95..    max
1    1.10   15.00 15.00  760  0.02  0.16  0.42   0.71   1.11    2.00    932
2   -0.49    0.85 -0.85    3 -6.63 -1.95 -0.94  -0.40   0.05    0.69      3
3  717.00 3148.00 16.00  403  1.14  6.00 24.00  80.00 300.00 2918.00  77776
4 1430.00 6224.00 14.00  296  1.52  8.00 40.00 148.00 594.00 5615.00 151195
     n
1 4046
2 4046
3 4046
```

which does show the last `n` column as integers without decimals, but not the rest columns!

But I would like this cell-varying formatting instead:

```
     mean      sd  skew kurt   min  X5.. X25.. median  X75..   X95..    max
1    1.10      15    15  760  0.02  0.16  0.42   0.71   1.11    2.00    932
2   -0.49    0.85 -0.85    3 -6.63 -1.95 -0.94  -0.40   0.05    0.69      3
3     717    3148    16  403  1.14     6    24     80    300    2918  77776
4    1430    6224    14  296  1.52     8    40    148    594    5615 151195
     n
1 4046
2 4046
3 4046
4 4046
```

Comment: @Zheyuan Li For some reason the browser did not show (red little icon on top) that there were 3 answers. Amazing. But I have probably did not phrase the question in the correct way, because of my insufficient knowledge. I think the problem is about formatting a data frame per cell, and not exclusively using the `round()` function per cell (as I accidentally probably misleadingly implied that I want). So in all the answers `desired.df` has the (2, a) element rounded to `123.00`, while I do not want the `.00`, but only the integer part, `123`.

Comment: I think this question is relevant, and I'll investigate it more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093416/write-a-dataframe-with-different-number-of-decimal-places-per-column-in-r

Comment: Yes that's correct, and this is why I modified the question so as to include only the integer part. (I actually modified it 1-2 minutes after posting it for the first time).

Comment: I will investigate it more. I will update the question using `dput` for the original data frame. Which clearly shows why I was unfortunately was mislead that `round()` should be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `round.my.way`works with `apply`. Use middle argument of `apply` like this for both rows and columns `c(1,2)`

```
apply(df,c(1,2),round.my.way)
      a      b
[1,]   0.12 321.00
[2,] 123.00   0.32
```

Other that might work as well,

Assumption 1: If you `cell` value `less than 2` then to `round to 2 decimal places else 0 decimal places`. This is based on the function you have written above.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0.123, 123.456), b = c(321.321, 0.321))
df <- as.matrix(df)
df1 <- ifelse(df < 2,round(df,2),round(df))
df1
#         a      b
# [1,]   0.12 321.00
# [2,] 123.00   0.32
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

Assumption 2: From you expected output, I assume that all your `diagonal elements (row number = column number) are rounded up to 2 decimal places` and rest to `0 decimal places`. If the assumption is correct, below here would be one of the solution:

```
  df <- data.frame(a = c(0.123, 123.456), b = c(321.321, 0.321))
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  df1 <- ifelse(row(df)==col(df),round(df,2),round(df))
  df1
  #      [,1]   [,2]
  # [1,]   0.12 321.00
  # [2,] 123.00   0.32
  df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

You can also use `floor` to print before decimals, but the output prints the number of digits after decimal as 2 or 3 whichever is highest in the dataframe, in this case we have `0` and `2` so, it `prints 2 decimal place for all elements`, if you `round` it to `3` decimal places, it `prints 321.000` for `df[1,2]` and `123.000` for `df[2,1]`

```
 df <- data.frame(a = c(0.123, 123.456), b = c(321.321, 0.321))
 df <- as.matrix(df)
 df1 <- ifelse(row(df)==col(df),round(df,2),floor(df))
 df1
 #      [,1]   [,2]
 # [1,]   0.12 321.00
 # [2,] 123.00   0.32
 df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

For 3 decimal places,

```
 df1 <- ifelse(row(df)==col(df),round(df,2),round(df))
 df1
 #      [,1]   [,2]
 # [1,]  0.123 321.000
 # [2,] 123.000   0.321
 df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```

Comment: @RichardScriven I don't want to pass any wrong information here, please correct me here so that I can improve this result. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see, yes Thank you. If I make a point there hope that would make sense by putting an if. Thank you so much for correcting me there. I will keep in mind.

Comment: Hi,  I converted it to matrix first, which I forgot to insert here, although the OP code is working, i will insert the `as.matrix()`, which I did, other wise the result was a `list` actually.

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution using a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x < 2, round(x, 2), round(x) ))]

#>        a      b
#> 1:   0.12 321.00
#> 2: 123.00   0.32
```